# SearchView always expanded, in the toolbar?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried several solutions here in stackoverflow, but none worked for me.

I have the icon in the toolbar and it expands when clicked and opens the activity to be done the search.
Codes below:

XML Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

</menu>
```

Activity Code:

```
class HomeActivity : LoggedActivity<ViewHomeBinding, HomeViewModel>(), HomeView {

    // ATTRIBUTES

    private var pagerAdapter: HomePagerAdapter? = null

    // BASE METHODS

    override fun onInject(component: LoggedActivityComponent) = component.inject(this)

    override val contentView = R.layout.view_home

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.item_search -> {
            startActivity(Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java))
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

I wish it would always be expanded.
And of the white color, since it expands green, is it possible?
Thank you

> I tried this in XML; android: iconifiedByDefault = "false" app:
>   iconifiedByDefault = "false"

EDIT:

Toobar XML in HomeActivity

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.plugapps.zuk.viewmodel.HomeViewModel"/>
</data>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You are setting it via a menu. Hence, you are getting an icon. What you will have to do it use include `Toolbar` in layout.xml and add a `SearchView`inside  `Toolbar`.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123262/6559031)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how the structure of your layout.xml will look. The you can apply whatever property you want to the layouts and views.

```
<LinerLayout>
    <Toolbar>
        <SearchView/>
    </Toolbar>
</LinerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your menu xml as follows

```
  app:showAsAction="always"
  app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
  android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
```